# Can't Get PS/2 Trackball to Work

Tags: mouse

I'm having serious issues trying to get a PS/2 trackball to work.  The trackball works under Windows, and I can get other PS/2 optical mice to work with my Linux distribution.  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 Kernel 3.19.0-43.

xinput shows my device listed as "PS/2 Generic Mouse" id=12, and "xinput list 12" shows 5 supported buttons, but "xinput test 12" generates no output when moving the trackball/clicking the mouse buttons.

cat /proc/bus/input/devices  returns:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="PS/2 Generic Mouse"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event4
B: PROP=1
B: EV=7
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
```

I've also tried

```
modprobe -r psmouse
modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

to no avail.

Relevant dmesg output from "dmesg | grep ouse" is:

```
mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
psmouse serio1: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio1
input: PS/2 Generic Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
psmouse serio1: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio1
```

It's been verified that the trackball *does* work on Windows NT, so it's definitely functional, but I'm all out of places to go.  Any ideas for what to look into?